# JS How can I check if an object has attributes no included in an interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have this interface

```
export interface IUser {
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
  state?: number;
}
```

and I receive this object

```
const payload = {
  name: 'name1',
  surename: 'surename1'
};
```

What I need is to reject this payload if it includes some attribute that is not included in the IUser interface, as surename in this example

Comment: FYI, an interface just guarantees that an object *has* certain properties, it does not and should not prevent the object from having *more* properties. There are of course valid reasons to want to shape an object to your exact expectations, just wanted to point out that this has little to do with the role of interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of the permitted properties, then check if `.some` one of the object properties are not in the array:

```
const permittedProperties = ['name', 'email', 'state'];

// ...

if (Object.keys(payload).some(key => !permittedProperties.includes(key))) {
  throw new Error('Invalid property found');
}
```

If the object may have properties on its *internal prototype(s)* that you also want to verify, you'll have to recursively iterate over each prototype object as well.

If you want to verify that no forbidden non-enumerable properties exist either, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` (which retrieves all own properties) instead of `Object.keys` (which only retrieves own enumerable properties).

Comment: It would be valid if I could iterate over interface properties, in order to get a general function that works for any other interface.The only valid properties are the interface properties

Comment: @Julitillo Interfaces do not exist at runtime, they're removed at compile time and only provide type information to the static type checker.

Comment: Emitted code contains Javascript only, and interfaces are not Javascript - they're for Typescript only. You could go the other way around though, if you wanted - from an arbitrary array of keys names, you could dynamically create an interface with those keys